# Angular filter search issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay so i was unsure what to call this question.

Usually you want to filter an `ng-repeat` on an id field however this poses a problem.

Say for instance you have the following array:

```
    $scope.objList = [
{id: 1, name:'A'},
{id: 2, name:'B'},
{id: 3, name:'C'},
{id: 4, name:'D'},
{id: 5, name:'E'},
{id: 6, name:'F'},
{id: 7, name:'G'},
{id: 8, name:'H'},
{id: 9, name:'I'},
{id: 10, name:'J'},
{id: 11, name:'K'}
];
```

Now you make the following `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objList | filter:search">
    <div>
     {{obj.id}}     {{obj.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

if you then set the `search` equal to: `search.id = 1`

You will get the following result:

```
1 A
10 J
11 K
```

So i guess my question is how can i avoid this so that the only result that comes is `1 A`.

Please note that i do know that in this example i would be able to just search for the `name` key however the above example is just to make a point.

You can find a fiddle of this issue here:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29357/)

Comment: The problem is that you are using a very old version of angularjs wich doesn't support `comparator` yet. Are you able to upgrade? I believe angularjs`v1.2.30` and above already supports `comparator` otherwise I sugest using a `function` as the `expression` for the `filterFilter` (i.e., `obj in objList | filter:myFilterExpression` where `myFilterExpression = function (value) : boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `:true` to match exact search.

```
 ng-repeat="obj in objList | filter:search:true"
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.objSelect = [{id: 1, name: 'A'}];
    
    
    $scope.objList = [
    {id: 1, name:'A'},
    {id: 2, name:'B'},
    {id: 3, name:'C'},
    {id: 4, name:'D'},
    {id: 5, name:'E'},
    {id: 6, name:'F'},
    {id: 7, name:'G'},
    {id: 8, name:'H'},
    {id: 9, name:'I'},
    {id: 10, name:'J'},
    {id: 11, name:'K'}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<select class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in objSelect" fix-select-null>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
    <div ng-repeat="obj in objList | filter:search:true">
        <div>
         {{obj.id}}     {{obj.name}}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: He added a JSFiddle where you can try this out. It doesn't work.

Comment: worth noting that this won't work in OP's fiddle since it has angular@1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a very old version of angularjs wich doesn't support comparator yet. Are you able to upgrade? I believe angularjs `v1.2.30` and above already supports comparator otherwise I sugest using a function as the expression for the filterFilter (i.e., `obj in objList | filter:myFilterExpression` where `myFilterExpression = function (value) : boolean`

### Fast Solution

Upgrade angularjs to `v1.2.30` at least and use `comparator` like so:

```
obj in objList | filter:search:true
```

### Use a function as the expression

```
obj in objList | filter:myFilter

$scope.myFilter = function (item) {
    return /* my filter criteria */;
};
```

### if you can't get rid of angularjs `v1.0.1`

You can apply a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) to the `filterFilter` within the angularjs module and override the original filter with `v1.2.30` filter logic (which by the way, I stole from [angularjs repositorie](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.30/src/ng/filter/filter.js)) that already has the comparator function in it. So that you can use the fast solution without having to upgrade.

```js
(function() { // begin hack
  angular.module('ng')
    .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
      $provide.decorator('filterFilter', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        var filterFilterv1_0_1 = $delegate;

        return filterFilterv1_2_30();
      }]);
    }]);

  function filterFilterv1_2_30() {
    return function(array, expression, comparator) {
      if (!angular.isArray(array)) return array;

      var comparatorType = typeof(comparator),
        predicates = [];

      predicates.check = function(value) {
        for (var j = 0; j < predicates.length; j++) {
          if (!predicates[j](value)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      };

      if (comparatorType !== 'function') {
        if (comparatorType === 'boolean' && comparator) {
          comparator = function(obj, text) {
            return angular.equals(obj, text);
          };
        } else {
          comparator = function(obj, text) {
            if (obj && text && typeof obj === 'object' && typeof text === 'object') {
              for (var objKey in obj) {
                if (objKey.charAt(0) !== '$' && hasOwnProperty.call(obj, objKey) &&
                  comparator(obj[objKey], text[objKey])) {
                  return true;
                }
              }
              return false;
            }
            text = ('' + text).toLowerCase();
            return ('' + obj).toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
          };
        }
      }

      var search = function(obj, text) {
        if (typeof text === 'string' && text.charAt(0) === '!') {
          return !search(obj, text.substr(1));
        }
        switch (typeof obj) {
          case 'boolean':
          case 'number':
          case 'string':
            return comparator(obj, text);
          case 'object':
            switch (typeof text) {
              case 'object':
                return comparator(obj, text);
              default:
                for (var objKey in obj) {
                  if (objKey.charAt(0) !== '$' && search(obj[objKey], text)) {
                    return true;
                  }
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
          case 'array':
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
              if (search(obj[i], text)) {
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          default:
            return false;
        }
      };
      switch (typeof expression) {
        case 'boolean':
        case 'number':
        case 'string':
          // Set up expression object and fall through
          expression = {
            $: expression
          };
          // jshint -W086
        case 'object':
          // jshint +W086
          for (var key in expression) {
            (function(path) {
              if (typeof expression[path] === 'undefined') return;
              predicates.push(function(value) {
                return search(path == '$' ? value : (value && value[path]), expression[path]);
              });
            })(key);
          }
          break;
        case 'function':
          predicates.push(expression);
          break;
        default:
          return array;
      }
      var filtered = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        var value = array[j];
        if (predicates.check(value)) {
          filtered.push(value);
        }
      }
      return filtered;
    };
  }
})();// end hack

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.objSelect = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'A'
  }];


  $scope.objList = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'A'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'B'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'C'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'D'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'E'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'F'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'G'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'H'
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: 'I'
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: 'J'
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: 'K'
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <select class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in objSelect" fix-select-null>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in objList | filter:search:true">
    <div>
      {{obj.id}} {{obj.name}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
```